# How to replace the column values of a dataframe into empty string which matches an input value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Input dataframe

```
val ds = Seq((1,"play Framwork"),
  (2,"Spark framework"),
  (3,"spring framework")).toDF("id","subject")
```

Expected dataframe

```
val ds = Seq((1,""),
  (2,"Spark framework"),
  (3,"spring framework")).toDF("id","subject")
```

Here the value `play Framwork` is replaced by empty string if my **search string** is `play Framwork` .

if my **search string** is `play` it should not replace the value in the cell .

when i use the below function

```
def replaceUsingRegEx(dataset: DataFrame, ColumnToBeTransformed: String, searchString: String): DataFrame = {
dataset.withColumn(ColumnToBeTransformed, regexp_replace(col(ColumnToBeTransformed), "(?i)" + searchString, ""))
```

}

it is actually replacing the value **play** into empty as follows .

```
val ds = Seq((1,"  Framwork"),
      (2,"Spark framework"),
      (3,"spring framework")).toDF("id","subject")
```

which is not expected behaviour . I want to replace the cell value only when the search string is completely matched with the cell value .

How can I modify the `regexp_replace` function to achieve the result as I need .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I want to replace the cell value only when the search string is completely matched with the cell value .

Instead of `regexp_replace` function you can use `when/otherwise` function as

```
def replaceUsingRegEx(dataset: DataFrame, ColumnToBeTransformed: String, searchString: String): DataFrame = {
  dataset.withColumn(ColumnToBeTransformed, when(col(ColumnToBeTransformed) === searchString, "").otherwise(col(ColumnToBeTransformed)))
}
```

So calling the function as

```
replaceUsingRegEx(ds, "subject", "play Framwork").show(false)
```

should give you

```
+---+----------------+
|id |subject         |
+---+----------------+
|1  |                |
|2  |Spark framework |
|3  |spring framework|
+---+----------------+
```

**Note that above function is case sensitive**, you can *equate lower cases if you want to ignore the case sensitive* as

```
def replaceUsingRegEx(dataset: DataFrame, ColumnToBeTransformed: String, searchString: String): DataFrame = {
  dataset.withColumn(ColumnToBeTransformed, when(lower(col(ColumnToBeTransformed)) === searchString.toLowerCase, "").otherwise(col(ColumnToBeTransformed)))
}
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: But how i can use some regex for replace the value  ?

Comment: if you use regex then then it will replace the matching strings and you will encounter the same problem you are having. so if you want to match whole text in a column  then when/otherwise is the good

Comment: why do you want to use regex when your requirement is met by when/otherwise? @adarshkadameri

Comment: `operator match {
      case "equals" => clearValueEquals(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
      case "contains" =>clearValueContains(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
      case "starts_with" => clearValueStartsWith(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
      case "ends_with" => clearValueEndsWith(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
      case "regex" => clearValueUsingRegex(ds,token,columnsToBeUpdated)
      case _ => throw new OperatorNotFoundException(s"${operatorAndTokenTuple._1} not applicable")
    }`

actually my requirement is to replace values by different ways like as above .

@Ramesh Maharajan

Comment: @adarshkadameri that seems like complicated and would require a lot of function other than regex. Ask another question with more details and I shall try to answer it. or somebody else will certainly help you . comments are not good for codes and not understandable

Comment: i have posted a question please check if you can help me @Ramesh Maharjan

Answer (score 0):

> def replaceUsingRegEx(dataset: DataFrame, ColumnToBeTransformed: String, searchString: String): DataFrame = {
>   dataset.withColumn(ColumnToBeTransformed, regexp_replace(col(ColumnToBeTransformed),searchString, ""))

Though there is no point of using reg ex in your scenario you can use conditional statement instead of this. But as per your request you can use reg ex to achieve this.